# Why String.prototype.split() Method Doesn't Respect Capturing Groups In A Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
const re = /([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(#[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)?(\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+)?/g
```

to parse strings like below:

```
const str = 'div#id.class.another-class'
```

When I use split:

```
str.split(re)
```

I get the following output:

```
["", "div", "#id", ".class.another", "-", "class", undefined, undefined, ""]
```

which also splits the string by "_" underscore.

I would expect the output as:

```
["", "div", "#id", ".class.another-class", "undefined", "undefined", ""]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Escape the hyphen in the `[...]` or put it at the start/end of the character class

Comment: Thanks. @WiktorStribiżew